# Opening multiple webbrowser windows in a loop.

Tags: vba, excel, activexobject

I have an excel spreadsheet and using VBA to code functions.  I am having a user enter X number entries into a spread sheet and want to be able to open X number of webbrowsers for each entry.  The webbrowsers will go to specific websites.  The code I have now works for one entry and I use Webbrowser1.Navigate to "CX".  What i want is if there are 5 entries for Webrowswer2....5.Navigate to  "CX".  Is there a way to have a dynamic webbrowser?

Comment: Perhaps show what code you have so far..

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not included any code, its a little difficult to see what you're doing so far.

If you add the "Microsoft Internet Explorer" reference to VBA you can create an array or browsers. You can do it without adding the reference using `CreateObject` but you wont get any intellitype help in the editor so might be harder if you don't know the control's methods etc

```
' Create a large array of them and initialise/destroy them as needed
Dim Browser(1 to 10) As InternetExplorer

' Init browser1
Set Browser(1) = New InternetExplorer

' Destroy browser1
Set Browser(1) = Nothing
```

Is there any reason you can just use one/two browsers and load the pages one after the other? Depending on what your goal is it might not help that much.